# Is there a sector by sector mirror imaging utility for Ubuntu?

Tags: server, backup, plex

I have been using headless Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for quite a while now and it's been updated every time there was an update, it's installed on my Dell PowerEdge T710 Server, and now every time I log in using SSH, I get a message saying that there's a major distro upgrade to 20.4 LTS.

The problem here is that after reading a lot of forums about upgrading, especially for servers, people have run into all sorts of problems and had to reformat and perform a fresh install, but doing this to my server is NOT an option, as I have too much on there to lose. The major problem I have is that I have 8 × 2 TB HD's configured as RAID 5, and I don't want to lose anything I have on them.

On a single HD PC workstation, I can use a mirror imaging software to create an image of the HD sector by sector, and store it on several DVD's, then if something did go wrong with the upgrade, then I can boot from the first DVD and restore the HD back as if nothing had happened, but is there something like that for RAID drives?

I want to create an image of my server, burn them on DVD's then using a restore utility as part of the first DVD, I could boot from the first DVD and restore everything back to how it was before anything happened, should the distro upgrade fail and I lose everything.

Backing up is NOT an option either, because using backup only backs up folders that are most common just as docs, downloads, etc., etc., but my server has stuff all over the place from web files to various PHP versions that can be selected by running a bash script I created, and, there's also other folder that have files in them, such as audio and video files for plex, plus on top of that there's bash script files in other places, so I would need a sector by sector backup, then a sector by sector restore should anything happen during the distro upgrade.

Comment: I would wait until 21.04LTS to upgrade. You have too much to risk, esp without current backups. Clonezilla or Macrium Reflect might be good backup choices. Clonezilla is good for clone or image, but clone copy can only go to a larger destination. Reflect is more portable and can do Windows and Ubuntu. Also check out TimeShift.

Comment: I agree with heynnema and I would suggest to start by fixing your server. All personal files and settings should be on a different partition that you mount to your system disc where after mounting use a script to copy files over to the system disc. That makes a backup easy: only thing you need to do is to `dd` or `rsync` your personal disk and you can always burn the system installation. Plus you really need a backup server ;-) also:you do not need a sector backup. rsync should be good enough for this. or `dd`